# Check if num can be divided by 1 (not 1.9, 2.5 but 1.0, 6.0)

Tags: python, range, generator

I need to write a generator that taking a range and every call yields the next float-step.

Python code:

```
def float_range(x, y, step):
    while x <= y:
        x = float(x)
        if x % 1 == 0: # Here is the problem
            yield int(x)
        else:
            yield x
        x += step
```

When a number can be divided by one, I should bring the number as an Integer but the `if` statement is never being true.
I've already tried `float.is_integer()`.

Comment: *"I've already tried float.is_integer()"* - how, and with what outcome?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want to know why x % 1 == 0 doesn't get True.

Comment: jonrsharpe - same - the expression doesn't get True

Comment: @Etgar: both `float.is_integer()` and `x % 1 == 0` are going to be false for the exact same reasons: You don't actually have a whole number. You have a whole number *plus or minus a tiny fraction*.

Comment: @vaultah: uhg, then you may as well pick any float-is-imprecise post to at least give a more helpful answer to this OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
def float_range(x, y, step):
    while x <= y:
        if round(x, 3) % 1 == 0:
            yield int(round(x))
        else:
            yield x
        x += step
```

When adding a lot of times 0.1 to x, there is a small deviation.
Rounding x solved my problem for small numbers.

Comment: I think the real question is "how close is close enough?". For your purposes, is 1.99, 1.999, 1.9999 close enough to 2 that you want it to yield 2? On the other side, there is 1.01, 1.001, 1.0001, etc. to consider.

Once you know that, then I think @Etgar has a good answer. Just change the "3" in his solution to whatever level of precision you require.